# I can not change the mode or submode of the current document in WinEdt 8

Tags: winedt, unix

WinEdt 8 adds the submode UNIX to the current document. I can not delete it in Document Setting.
Why does WinEdt 8 do so?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This because your document has LF EOLN format (UNIX format).

If you want to change it to CR+LF (Windows format) open the 'Document Settings' dialog, go to the 'Options' page and in 'EOLN Format' choose 'CR+LF (PC)'.

Note that, after pressing 'OK', the status line still shows `TeX:UNIX`. This because WinEdt saves the "mode" of your document in a project file and changing the EOLN format doesn't modify the project file.

So you have to go to the 'Properties' page of the 'Document Settings' dialog and manually change the 'Document Mode' from `TeX:UNIX` to simply `TeX` and press 'OK'.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you. But how can it happened? I do not use UNIX. I loaded a file that was created by ordinary Windows.

Comment: @Vitalii I don't know. Probably it has been saved with LF line terminators. PS: please consider marking the answer as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below its vote count, if it has solved your problem.

Comment: Thank you. I can not find "Accepted'. I am sorry.

Comment: I suppose that now I have found the correct checkmark. Thanks again.